# Python Multithreading how can I optionally run a class or some code as another thread or synchronously

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

How can I have a class in python, that can be run in a separate thread OR be run synchronously. Just to be clear, I have no questions about creating a thread.

If I have a `class MyClass(threading.Thread):` Then this will always be created as a separate thread, which needs to have its start method called.

I want to avoid duplicating the class again and I'm wondering if I can have the cake and eat it too :)

Side question: Has anyone got python threads to work on kubernetes? Mine just turn into full syncro code. I can't seem to find any resources on this which leads me to think I am doing something very wrong.

Comment: What do you mean? _Every_ class in Python can be run synchronously or run in a separate thread.  "Run" means that the class has some method that can be called by other code. "...in a separate thread" means that you write code to create a new thread just for the purpose of calling the method.  "Run synchronously" you just write code that calls the method without thinking about threads.

Comment: And the threaded class needs to have its start method called, can I still call any other method within the class is what I'm asking

Comment: Of course! You can always write code that calls any method of any object.